# Using "from in" in a LinqSpecs specification?

Tags: linq, linq-to-nhibernate

We're using LinqSpecs to create specifications for our NHibernate Linq queries and I have  the following query:

```
from p in projects
  from pp in p.Personprojects
  where pp.Id.PersonId == userId
  select p
```

And I'd like to encapsulate the

```
 from pp in p.Personprojects   
 where pp.Id.PersonId == userId
```

part in a specification.

Is there any way to do that?

My current solution is

```
public override Expression<Func<Project, bool>> IsSatisfiedBy()
{
  return p => p.Personprojects.Count(pp => pp.Id.PersonId == _userId)>0;
}
```

which doesn't strike me as optimal...

Answer (score 2):

Instead of comparing `Count` to 0, it's better to use `Any`:

```
public override Expression<Func<Project, bool>> IsSatisfiedBy()
{
    return p => p.Personprojects.Any(pp => pp.Id.PersonId == _userId);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that´s an improvement, but how does it compare to joining the table in the from statement?